# which is difference between static and dynamic website both developed with coding?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a doubt: what is the difference between a static and a dynamic site both developed with html / css / js code etc ...? Would you also have some examples to show me?

Comment: A static website doesn't have any content that changes on the fly. It's just text and images.

Comment: are you referring to animations and the like? Because I hear a lot of versions, some talk about websites dealing with databases, links based on people's interests like social media.

Comment: The terms are somewhat fuzzy and do vary in meaning with context.

Comment: No, I'm referring to content that may change over time (e.g. a stock price website) or is related to which user is using the site.

Comment: Okay, so, for example, an informational-only website can be considered static, right?

Comment: Wrong. An informational-only website can be generated dynamically with server side code and can use dynamic client-side code.

Comment: Dynamic is like when you have a template. E.g. this site is dynamic, you can make as many new questions as you want, they are stored in a database and when you load a question, it takes the data from the database for that question and puts it into a ready made html layout - that's why all the questions have the same basic appearance. There is not literally a separate html page stored on the server for each question

Answer (score 1):

Static site is a site that serves content as it's stored. Whereas, a dynamic site usually have a database where it pulls information when requested.

This is a static site https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/glitch-hello-website

This is a dynamic site https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/glitch-hello-node